# SQL Server 2008: copy table structure, and schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema

thanks for your time. i edited my script, ran it, and still got this name: srp.dbo.gstDataCutover. i used to be able to do this easily with MSSQL2005. we've recently upgraded to 2008. and i dont remember doing it any other way...

Hi,

I'm trying to copy a table structure (columns, datatypes, schema) into a new table to have the same schema and structure, using the sql code below.

```
SELECT     dbo.gstData.*
INTO            [dbo.gstDataCutover]
FROM         dbo.gstData
WHERE      dbo.gstData.gstID < 1
```

My problem is, when i run this script the new table `dbo.gstDataCutover` is named as "dbo.gstDataCutover" but the schema is defaulted to the system schema ("srp"), which is actually `srp.[dbo.gstDataCutover]`.

I want to copy both the structure and the schema.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Without any periods, the hard brackets indicate table name -- it's including the "dbo." in your example as part of the table name.

If you want the table created in the dbo schema:

```
SELECT t.*
  INTO dbo.gstDataCutover
  FROM dbo.gstData t
 WHERE t.gstID < 1
```

Likewise, if you want the table created in the srp schema:

```
SELECT t.*
  INTO srp.gstDataCutover
  FROM dbo.gstData t
 WHERE t.gstID < 1
```

The table name doesn't have any unusual characters, so there's no need to use hard brackets...

Comment: your brackets should enclose individual objects rather then the entire object graph.  eg   [dbo].[gstDataCutver] and [srp].[gstDataCutover] rather than [dbo.gstDataCutover]

Comment: @BozoJoe: Your comment doesn't apply to my answer, but the question posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the community edition of Visual Studio, which has features for comparing schemas as well as data. It will list the differences and allows you to select a set of changes, for which it will generate an update-script.

[image]